# Nested aggregation on unmapped field

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to perform a scripted aggregation on a nested field in elastic. The complication being that my field is not included in the mapping at all. The mapping is:

```
{
    "my_index": {
        "my_type": {
            "properties": {
                "Fields": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "dynamic": "false",
                    "properties": {
                        "fieldname": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "index": "not_analyzed"
                        },
                        "filtered": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "analyzer": "keyword"
                        },
                        "index": {
                            "type": "integer"
                        },
                        "policy": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "index": "not_analyzed"
                        },
                        "profile": {
                            "type": "boolean"
                        },
                        "result": {
                            "type": "integer"
                        },
                        "type": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "index": "not_analyzed"
                        },
                        "uri": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "index": "not_analyzed"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the aggregation query I am performing

```
POST my_index/my_type/_search
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "fields": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "Fields"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "distinct_content": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "Fields.content"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However I get no results for the nested aggregation. I tried using a scripted_metric aggregation, but I still didn't seem to be able to access the content field. Is it possible to access fields that are not mapped at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you disabled dynamic mapping you cannot access this field by search or aggregation. See bottom note of this [documentation site](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/dynamic-mapping.html) (it is general mapping note, but it is also appliable to nested objects).

Nevertheless you can easily extend mapping with [PUT mapping API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html) then reindex and it should be accessible.